# R - generate a sequence of letters and numbers

Tags: r

I am trying to create the following vector in R:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
```

I am using the following code:

```
paste0(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 3), rep(1:3, 3))
```

But instead I'm getting the following sequence:

```
"A1" "B2" "C3" "D1" "E2" "A3" "B1" "C2" "D3" "E1" "A2" "B3" "C1" "D2" "E3"
```

So the problem is that `1:3` also starts cycling whereas I would first like to complete the `A-E` cycle with suffix 1 and then initiate the next `A-E` cycle with suffix 2.

How can I generate the vector I need?

Comment: do oyu want `rep(1:3, each=5)`?

Comment: Try `outer`: `c(outer(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),1:3,paste0))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```r
paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3), rep(1:3, each = 5))
#> [1] "A1" "B1" "C1" "D1" "E1" "A2" "B2" "C2" "D2" "E2" "A3" "B3" "C3" "D3" "E3"
```

Comment: Without explicit `rep`, one can use `outer`: `c(outer(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),1:3,paste0))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `expand.gird` with `paste` via `do.call` and use `LETTERS` and `1:3`.

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(LETTERS[1:5], 1:3))
#[1] "A1" "B1" "C1" "D1" "E1" "A2" "B2" "C2" "D2" "E2" "A3" "B3" "C3" "D3" "E3"
```

In case the output should be a `factor` `expand.grid` with `interaction` could be used.

```
interaction(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:5], 1:3), sep="")
# [1] A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
#Levels: A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 A3 B3 C3 D3 E3
```

Comment: 50 milliseconds between these two answers!